# What is the easiest way to run bash dependent dockerfiles on windows?

Tags: windows, bash, docker, powershell

I need to setup docker on my windows 10 OS. I've previously been a linux guy where everything just works so this is a pain for me. It works as expected but within the dockerfile there are calls that uses /bin/bash which makes the build fail.
I've tried to setup a VM with hyper-v but then i stopped because i figured there must be an easier way. I found the bash.exe in windows. i can't run as sudo but i guess that doesn't matter here as long as i run bash as administrator. wget works here but the docker program cant be found when i run docker --version.

Is the easiest way to run bash scripts on win10 with the bash.exe? And why can't docker run in the bash terminal (there is no .bashrc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [Linux on the Windows box](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/how-to-install-wsl2-on-windows-10). The two systems can access each other's file systems (`\\wsl$`, `/mnt/c`). I use Ubuntu, and it's as if I was using a "normal" Ubuntu box in all aspects, so far. I'd be surprised if your process didn't work here.

Alternatively, there's [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). When running Cygwin, you're kinda in a VM, kinda not. It's a bit blurry. As such, it's not as robust as WSL. But it might do the trick, and it's a lot less "heavy" than installing a full Linux distro.

Comment: The cygwin was super straight forward. thanks!